# Elasticsearch _aliases in Template?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
   POST /_aliases
    {
        "actions" : [
            { "add" : { "index" : "test*", "alias" : "all_test" } }
        ]
    }
```

1)Based on the above configuration all the indices that start with test and also that are present in the cluster at that point of time will be kept in all_test alias.

2)If i create alias in Template by using below configuration

```
PUT localhost:9200/_template/test -d '
{
  "template" : "test*",
  "aliases" : {
    "all_test" : {}
  } 
}
```

This will send the future indices which starts with test* to all_test alias.

Can i able to do 1+2 = I want  to send the existing indices and the future indices to particular alias which i will define in ES Template?

If it is possible can you please share the sample template code for the above usecase?

Thanks

Comment: A new template will only be used when future indices will be created. For existing indices, you need to use option 1.

Comment: That means you are saying we can't combine both 1 and 2 usecases together

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you cannot have an alias definition inside a template.

Comment: In one template can i give mutiple match conditions like if  `"template" : "test*" `then create `"test_alias"` and `"template": "exam*"` then create `"exam_alias"`.

Comment: You simply need to create different templates

Comment: Thanks val..it helped but i want to know is there any other possible way i can able to acheive the above usecase because i want all the existing and the upcoming indices to stored in one alias.

Comment: Why can't you just run option 1 (for existing indices) and then option 2 (for all new indices) ?

Comment: I got it val ..Why i asked again is i want to automate everything in the template itself .Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: If you think this can be useful to other people, you can still develop the feature and submit a Pull Request in the Elasticsearch repository